# Python, I want user to input text file

Tags: python, tkinter, cpu-word

Hello currently I'm working on a word occurrence counter, I created a gui for it where users can type the words and then press the "count" button and it will count the occurence of each word, however I want to make it so user can instead upload a text file and the word occurrence will count the occurence of each word in the text file instead. Does anyone know how to make the transition? I need to know how to change it from user input words to user upload text files.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from collections import Counter

#Functions
def countWords(s):
    signos = [',', '.', ';', ':']
    cleanstr = ''
    for letra in s.lower():
        if letra in signos:
            cleanstr += ''
        else:
            cleanstr += letra
    strlist = cleanstr.split(' ')
    return dict(Counter(strlist))


def button_count():
    text = mainWindow.e2.get()

    count = countWords(text)
    myLabel = Label(root, text=count)
    myLabel.pack()


#Graphics
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Count words")
root.geometry('400x400')

#Background Image Label
bg = PhotoImage(file = "./guibackground.gif")

# Show image using label 
label1 = Label( root, image = bg) 
label1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER) 


#Class Window
class Window:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.e2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=self.e2, width=35, borderwidth=5)
        self.e.pack()

        self.button = Button(root, text="Count words", command=button_count)
        self.button.pack()
        self.exit_button = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.quit)
        self.exit_button.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    mainWindow = Window(root)
```

Comment: Use `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename` to get the file path?

Answer (score 0):

Use `filedialog.askopenfilename` method:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from collections import Counter

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.btn = tk.Button(text='Open File', command=self.open_file)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.lbl = tk.Label()
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def open_file(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', title='Select file', filetypes=(('text files','*.txt'), ('all files','*.*')))
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            self.lbl.configure(text=f'{Counter(f.read().split())}')

App()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you, that really helped with my problem. Have a good day